# django is there better variant to use CBV approach in my project?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-class-based-views

Sorry for such a long question and my bad english. I have finished Python Crash Course, an introductory programming book by Eric Matthes. After that decided to continue study Django and found that CBV  method is more acceptable for site creating. I rewrited via CBV training program from the book which was written by functions, but I still feel a bit lost with methods of CBV after reading the official documentation.
Could somebody tell, is there a lot of hardcoding in my CBV variant? And it's possible to do it better ?

Every variant works fine.

Here the variant of views from the books with comments, I inserted a comments to understand what code does:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.http import Http404
from .models import Topic, Entry
from .forms import TopicForm, EntryForm

# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    """Home page of Learning Log."""
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/index.html')

def more_inf(request):
    return render(request,'learning_logs/more_inf.html')

def topics(request):
    """List of topics"""
    public_topics = Topic.objects.filter(public=True).order_by('date_added')
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        private_topics = Topic.objects.filter(owner=request.user).order_by('date_added')
        topics = public_topics | private_topics
    else:
        topics = public_topics
    
    context = {'topics': topics}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/topics.html', context)

@login_required
def topic(request, topic_id):
    """Show one topic with details"""
    topic = get_object_or_404(Topic, id=topic_id)
    #Проверка того, что тема принадлежит текущему пользователю
    check_topic_owner(topic.owner, request)

    entries = topic.entry_set.order_by('-date_added')
    context = {'topic': topic, 'entries': entries}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/topic.html', context)

@login_required
def new_topic(request):
    """Create new topic"""
    if request.method != 'POST':
        #data wasn't sent;create empty form
        form = TopicForm()
    else:
        #POST data sent; to process the data.
        form = TopicForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_topic = form.save(commit=False)
            new_topic.owner = request.user
            new_topic.save()
            return redirect('learning_logs:topics')

    #Show empty or invalid form.
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/new_topic.html', context)

@login_required
def new_entry(request, topic_id):
    """Add new entry to the topic"""
    topic = get_object_or_404(Topic, id=topic_id)
    check_topic_owner(topic.owner, request)
    if request.method != 'POST':
        #data wasn't sent;create empty form
        form = EntryForm()
    else:
        #POST data sent; to process the data.
        form = EntryForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_entry = form.save(commit=False)
            new_entry.topic = topic
            new_entry.save()
            return redirect('learning_logs:topic', topic_id=topic_id)

    #Show empty or invalid form.
    context = {'topic': topic, 'form': form}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/new_entry.html', context)

@login_required
def edit_entry(request, entry_id):
    """Edit the current entry"""
    entry = get_object_or_404(Entry, id=entry_id)
    topic = entry.topic
    check_topic_owner(topic.owner, request)

    if request.method !='POST':
        #initial request; form was created by current data entries
        form = EntryForm(instance=entry)
    else:
        #POST data sent; to process the data.
        form = EntryForm(instance=entry, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('learning_logs:topic', topic_id=topic.id)

    context = {'entry': entry, 'topic': topic, 'form': form}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/edit_entry.html', context)

def check_topic_owner(owner, request):
    if owner != request.user:
        raise Http404
```

There is my new CBV variant, also with slugs added and absolute_url:
What can I improve there? Thank you in advance

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.http import Http404
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView, CreateView, UpdateView
from .models import Topic, Entry
from .forms import TopicForm, EntryForm

# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    """Домашняя страница приложения Learning Log."""
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/index.html')

def more_inf(request):
    return render(request,'learning_logs/more_inf.html')

class TopicsHome(ListView):
    model = Topic
    template_name = 'learning_logs/topics.html'
    context_object_name = 'topics'
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        public_topics = Topic.objects.filter(public=True).order_by('date_added')
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            private_topics = Topic.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user).order_by('date_added')
            topics = public_topics | private_topics
        else:
            topics = public_topics
        return topics


class ShowTopic(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = Topic
    template_name = 'learning_logs/topic.html'
    context_object_name = 'topic'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'topic_slug'
  
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        topic = get_object_or_404(Topic, slug=self.kwargs['topic_slug'])
        check_topic_owner(topic.owner, self.request)
        context['entries'] = topic.entry_set.order_by('-date_added')
        return context


class AddTopic(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):  
    form_class = TopicForm
    template_name = 'learning_logs/new_topic.html'  

    def form_valid(self, form):
        new_topic = form.save(commit=False)
        new_topic.owner = self.request.user
        new_topic.save()
        return redirect('learning_logs:topics')
    
class AddEntry(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    form_class = EntryForm
    template_name = 'learning_logs/new_entry.html'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'topic_slug'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        topic = get_object_or_404(Topic, slug=self.kwargs['topic_slug'])
        check_topic_owner(topic.owner, self.request)
        new_entry = form.save(commit=False)
        new_entry.topic = topic
        new_entry.save()
        return redirect('learning_logs:topic', topic_slug=topic.slug)


class EditEntry(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Entry
    form_class = EntryForm
    template_name = 'learning_logs/edit_entry.html'
    context_object_name = 'topic'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'entry_slug'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        entry = get_object_or_404(Entry, slug=self.kwargs['entry_slug'])
        topic = entry.topic
        check_topic_owner(topic.owner, self.request)
        form.save()
        return redirect('learning_logs:topic', topic_slug=topic.slug)


def check_topic_owner(owner, request):
    if owner != request.user:
        raise Http404
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function Based Views (FBV) and Class Based Views (CBV) both have their place in  Django projects. It usually boils down to developer preference. Personally, I prefer FBV because there is less abstraction. Though there is nothing wrong with going the CBV route either!

If you want to read more about FBV and why one might prefer this, check out this series of articles: https://spookylukey.github.io/django-views-the-right-way/

Comment: I will read, thank you!